# UITableView using instance methods

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've been trying to access some instance methods of UITableView inside my UITableView class to use a NSFetchedResultsController following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

In the tutorial there is a section of code where you're accessing self.tableView, which makes sense because you're using a UITableViewController. However, I am trying to use a UITableView and I can't find any examples that use that.

Looking at the documentation, I should have an instance method "beginUpdates" among other things (reloadUpdates, insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

However, when I try to access the instance method with [self beginUpdates] I can't get the instance method (Method not found).  It's like that for a bunch of the instance methods, but not all of them.  For example, I can access

```
[self setEditing:(BOOL) animated:(BOOL)]
```

I'm rather new to Objective-C so I believe I'm accessing my UITableView instance in the wrong fashion, but the only thing I can think of with that class is "self"

How do I go about accessing those methods in UITableView rather than UITableViewController?

Comment: So you're subclassing `UITableView`?

Comment: Thank you, I blatantly missed that.  I changed the inheritance from UIViewController to UITableView and it worked.

Comment: Don't Do That(tm). These methods belong in a view controller, not in UITableView. If you're not using a UITableViewController but a regular UIViewController, then add the table view as a property to that view controller. If you name it `self.tableView` then you should be able to use it exactly as in the tutorial you mentioned.

Comment: I realized this later and set up the appropriate IBOutlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 @Hollance's comment. You may find that you want to customize your view controller logic more than subclassing `UITableViewController` allows, but this would be better served by a subclass of `UIViewController` that is composed with a `UITableView` (i.e., the `tableView` outlet/property).